# Render tiles disappeared and now render times are higher. How to fix?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, tilesize

I was going through tutorial and I got to the final part which is rendering. I was messing around with settings as it was shown in the tutorial and started rendering. Those were test renders and I was just messing with render tile sizes. Then I started rendering probably the forth time and both of my screens went black, then they turned on again and other background processes turned off except the browser. I turned the blender on again and found out that I can's see render tiles and render times increased from 22.90 seconds from previous renders before the whole chaos happened, to 35.23.

I tried reinstalling and messing with the settings again - nothing happened.
I loaded factory settings in - nothing changed.
I rebooted my computer and nothing again.

Please help!

Here's the link to the video so you get a better understanding of what I mean
https://www.dropbox.com/s/om8rkrpvcmmq3bx/2018-08-21%2018-00-46.mp4?dl=0

My Hardware:

CPU: Ryzen 1700x
GPU: GeForce GTX 750ti
RAM: 16gb DDR4 3200mhz
MB: MSI B350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable progressive refine.

[image: Progressive Refine]